# Boltzmann factor predicts arbitrarily large numbers of electrons at high potential?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, plasma-physics

In deriving the Debye shielding length we are told that the Boltzmann factor for particles of charge $q$ is:

$n_{q}=n_{0}\exp(-q\phi/kT)$

If we assume the potential $\phi$ is positive, then the electrons have a positive argument in the exponent. This means there are arbitrarily large numbers of electrons to be found at high potential. The only resolution of this problem is that the potential must be small.

How can one show that the potential is small? (or alternatively is there another way to explain the problem of large numbers of electrons at high potential?)

Comment: Why do you say "arbitrarily large"?  The density of electrons will be higher where the potential is higher, but not arbitrarily so.

Comment: @garyp Good point, I suppose I had in mind a point charge and imagined the potential becoming arbitrarily large on approaching it.